# Noob Student Having trouble on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble with the class work. Im a mature age student whos trying to play catch up haha.
We are using RUBY in class

```
# Fix up the following code that it works and produces the expected output
# in the task specification.

# Asks the user to enter their age and returns an integer age
def get_age()
  puts "Enter your age in years: "
  age = gets.to_i
  return age
end

# takes a prompt and displays it to the user then returns the
# entered string
def get_string()
  puts "Enter your name: "
  name = gets
  return name
end

# Calculate the year born based on the parameter age and print that out
# along with the name of the user
def print_year_born(age)
  year_born = Date.today.year -  get_age
  puts "You were born in: " + year_born
  return year_born
end

def main
  age = get_age()
  name = get_string()
  print_year_born
(age)
end

main
```

I am having trouble in the line ..

```
def print_year_born = Date.today.year - get_age
puts "You were born in: " + year_born
return year_born
end
```

The issue im having is age has already been found but it's in the other procedure get_age
how do I call get_age in this procedure?

Thanks in advance- Student

Comment: Isn't `age` already in the parameter above at `def print_year_born(age)`? Why should you call `get_age?` again then?

Comment: Your definition of def print_year_born(age) does not need an argument given the contents of the procedure and should be simply `def_print_year_born()`.   The call to `get_age` inside the procedure will invoke that procedure and return the value required as an integer.  The value `year_born` should then be cast to a string in the print command.  As you used `puts` the correct syntax is `puts "You were born in:  #{year_born}"` using interpolation.  Alternatively you can do this: `puts "You were born in: " + year_born.to_s`  but that sort of defeats the idea of using `puts` to begin with

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, you got the age in `get_age`

So instead of

```
year_born = Date.today.year - get_age
```

which requests it again, you need to do

```
year_born = Date.today.year - age
```

`age` being the argument that you passed into the print_year_born method

Plus it may be a typo, but you want

```
print_year_born(age)
```

as one line

Comment: Hi there. Thanks alot for helping. I tried that and keep getting the error:
```
Enter your age in years:
21
Enter your name:
rey
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from debug.rb:34:in `<main>'
        1: from debug.rb:31:in `main'
debug.rb:23:in `print_year_born': uninitialized constant Date (NameError)
Did you mean?  Data
```

Comment: For some reason Date.today.year doesnt seem to be working in this file, have I done something wrong here? Worked in my other one when I used Date.today.year - age 
:(

Comment: `Date` comes from rails, you probably don't use it.

Comment: `Date.today` is a standard ruby class & method: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today however it is not autoloaded so you may need `require 'date'`

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same task. I might be a bit late to answer but you need to define date at the beginning of the coding.
In row three you need to enter the following:
require 'date'

This will fix your issue.
However I have an issue with:
def print_year_born(age)
year_born = Date.today.year -  age
puts(name.to_s + "You were born in: " + year_born.to_s)
end

The outcome should be: "name" you were born in: "year".
I can't figure out how to get the name it appear.
NOTE: Coding is the exact same as the above question

Answer (score 0):

This is a representative answer to your requirement.  You need to familiarise yourself with the concept of nested procedure calls.  These are at the heart of OOP.  The idea being that the message is all the caller needs from the provider and that the caller speaks directly to the provider, who may make their own requests of other providers, without intervening procedural code to hold state or values.

```
def get_age()
  puts "Enter your age in years: "
  age = gets.to_i
  return age
end

require 'date'

def print_year_born
  year_born = Date.today.year -  get_age
  puts "You were born in:  #{year_born}"
  # or even more simply
  puts "You were born in:  #{Date.today.year - get_age}"
end

print_year_born

Enter your age in years: 
 12
You were born in:  2008
Enter your age in years: 
 12
You were born in:  2008
```